# Subsetting dataframe using brackets in R - Error in -x: invalid argument to unary operator

Tags: r, subset

I am trying to make all columns numeric except the ones specified in "notnumeric" and "singlecombcols".

```
notnumeric <- c(40, 42:47, 61:62)
df[,-notnumeric] <- sapply(df[,-notnumeric], as.numeric)

singlecombcols <- c("singlecomb_1", "singlecomb_2", "singlecomb_3", "singlecomb_4")
df[,-singlecombcols] <- sapply(df[,-singlecombcols], as.numeric)
```

In the past, I have used this exact type of code successfully. However, I am now getting the following error messages:

```
Error in -notnumeric : invalid argument to unary operator
Error in -singlecombcols : invalid argument to unary operator
```

When I remove the "-" before the variable names, I am able to run it. Has something changed in R that no longer allows me to use "-" to specify that I want to apply a function to all columns except those specified by the given object?

Comment: Yes, will add an example. Just checked and I get the same error with lapply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the second part that is an issue i.e. the numeric index can have `-`, but with column names, we need either `setdiff`

```
nm1 <- setdiff(names(df), singlecombcols)
df[nm1] <- lapply(df[nm1], as.numeric)
```

---

or `%in%` and `!`

```
i1 <- !names(df) %in% singlecombcols
df[i1] <- lapply(df[i1], as.numeric)
```

Comment: Why is it df[nm1] instead of df[,nm1] ? Is there a difference?

Comment: @melbez with `data.frame`, we use `row,column` to separate a `,`.  If we don't specify the `,`, it is a column index by default and since you are using to subset columns, it is not needed.  Also, if there are only a single column, the `,` could lead to `drop = TRUE` (by default) and coerce the data.frame to a vector